# PDF file is corrupted, after request.get() with python

Tags: python, pdf, request

So I have this simple code, but every time I try to open the downloaded pdf file, it says, that it's corrupted. It works for most test PDF files I found, so I know, that there is an issue with this particular, but I dont know, how to fix it.

```
import requests

url = 'https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-662-58392-0.pdf'
r = requests.get(url)

with open('python.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: Enter the URL in your browser and see how you are redirected.

Comment: Okay there is the problem, because if I enter the URL, I get the pdf in my browser, maybe because I am logged in at the [website](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-662-58392-0) and have the permission to download this pdf. I can also download it from my browser, but I wanted to try it with python. Do you know a possible solution? @ThierryLathuille

Answer (score 0):

Visiting that URL redirects to [this web page](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-662-58392-0).  It doesn't download a pdf.

What you are saving to `python.pdf` is the HTML of the web page, which is why PDF readers think it is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if the publisher's link doesn't work because it's not recognizing the session as one with paid access.

Try this scihub link instead: `https://sci-hub.tw/https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-662-58392-0.pdf`

Edit: Forgot to add that you'll need to wrangle it a bit to pull the pdf out of the pdf viewer div that shows on the right. This answer to a question about pulling pdf from scihub should work well: https://superuser.com/a/1101876